# How to set multiple parameters when querying in GAE with JDO in java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I'm following the docs on this site: http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/queries.html

From there I learned how to make queries but I seems only to work with one parameter. Here's how I'm doing it successfully:

```
javax.jdo.Query q1 = pm.newQuery(Player.class);

q1.setFilter("isOpen == true");

List<Player> players = (List<Player>) q1.execute();
```

That fetches me all the Player object with the boolean isOpen == true. I can do the same thing with a Long, that works too.

Here's the problem: When combining two conditions like this:

```
javax.jdo.Query q1 = pm.newQuery(Player.class);

q1.setFilter("isOpen == true && lastPing > 100");

List<Player> players = (List<Player>) q1.execute();
```

The app crashes. Here's the error I'm getting:

> Uncaught exception from servlet
>   com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreNeedIndexException: no
>   matching index found. The suggested index for this query is:
>   datastore-index kind="Player" ancestor="false" source="manual"
>   property name="isOpen" direction="asc" property name="lastPing"
>   direction="asc" datastore-index

So, does anyone know why this is happening? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Errm, the datastore needs "lastPing" indexing first ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do an inequality filter along with another filter unless you have an index on the column for which you're doing the inequality comparison. Add this to your `datastore-indexes.xml` in your `WEB-INF` folder and deploy it (either a full deploy or appcfg update-indexes):

```
<datastore-index kind="Player" ancestor="false">
        <property name="isOpen" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="lastPing" direction="asc"/>
    </datastore-index>
```